# Splitting input

Tags: java, input, split

Does anybody knows how could i split inputs like:

```
P K K R
K P K V
```

to different strings?
Right now my code is like that, but it throws error after the first line, because the lane switch is \n (enter) not an space

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] input = new String[7];
  String c1, c2, c3, c4, q1, q2, q3, q4;
  input = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
  c1= input[0];
  c2= input[1];
  c3= input[2];
  c4= input[3];
  q1= input[4];
  q2= input[5];
  q3= input[6];
  q4= input[7];
```

Comment: Still throws error after first line. :/

Comment: you want to write these 8 char with a \n and then the code have to read it and split ? Why not all the 8 on same line ?^^

Comment: School Work. Bot throws inputs like that :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] input = new String[7];
String c1, c2, c3, c4, q1, q2, q3, q4;

c1= sc.next().charAt(0)+"";
c2= sc.next().charAt(0)+"";
c3= sc.next().charAt(0)+"";
c4= sc.next().charAt(0)+"";
q1= sc.next().charAt(0)+"";
q2= sc.next().charAt(0)+"";
q3= sc.next().charAt(0)+"";
q4= sc.next().charAt(0)+"";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use StringTokenizer class

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] input = new String[7];
String c1, c2, c3, c4, q1, q2, q3, q4;

String s=sc.nextLine();
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(s);

c1= st.nextToken();
c2= st.nextToken();
c3= st.nextToken();
c4= st.nextToken();

s=sc.nextLine();
st=new StringTokenizer(s);

q1= st.nextToken();
q2= st.nextToken();
q3= st.nextToken();
q4= st.nextToken();
```